# Apple IAP & Third Part Subscriptions

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase, subscription

I know this has been asked so many times. But I don't really got an answer as this is not very clear.

I'm developing a web platform and an iOS app (linked together).

I have my own users base, and I don't rely on Apple IDs. So I can't use In-App Purchases because subscriptions would be linked to a given Apple ID and not my own IDs. Which can be confusing because a same user ID can run on devices with different Apple IDs, and vice-versa.

Moreover my users must be able to use the web platform with the same subscriptions/permissions online.

So I need to use a third-part service like Stripe to handle subscriptions.

If I do well understand the new Apple Guidelines, I can't put the Stripe form into the App. I can't neither put a link to make the payment on Safari, for example.

But what if I just put a label saying "Manage your subscription on my-website.com"?
Will my app be rejected by Apple?

This is not very clear as Apple says that "Developers can send communications outside of the app to their user base about purchasing methods other than in-app purchase."so we should be able to use third-part tools, without referring to them into the app..

Comment: The only way you can find out for sure what Apple will approve is to submit your app for review, but in my opinion having that label in your app would definitely lead to rejection. You can still use IAP for your app.  First, people rarely use different AppleIDs on different devices, but you can associate the subscription "original purchase id" with your user account. If someone attempts to associate that same purchase id with a different account you can either reject the activation or transfer the subscription. [RevenueCat documentation](https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/restoring-purchases)

Answer (score 1):

The canonical answer to your question is in [the Business section of the App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase).  Of particular note:

> **3.1.1 In-App Purchase:**
>
> - If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, cryptocurrencies and cryptocurrency wallets, etc. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase, except as set forth in 3.1.3(a).

And:

> **3.1.3(a) “Reader” Apps:** Apps may allow a user to access previously purchased content or content subscriptions (specifically: magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video). Reader apps may offer account creation for free tiers, and account management functionality for existing customers. Reader app developers may apply for the External Link Account Entitlement to provide an informational link in their app to a web site the developer owns or maintains responsibility for in order to create or manage an account. Learn more about the External Link Account Entitlement.

In short, if your subscription unlocks features or functionality in your app you have to use in-app purchases unless you have a "reader" app, in which case you can apply for an entitlement to add an external link to subscribe.  You will not be able to use Stripe to accept payment inside your app unless you're selling something like physical goods:

> **3.1.3(e) Goods and Services Outside of the App:** If your app enables people to purchase physical goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.

Ultimately it's up to Apple when it comes to what will pass review and what won't.  No one can predict what will happen ahead of time.